# BeautifulSoup HTML extracting tabular data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, extract

I have this HTML table, and I need some data from it:

```
<table id="curFullTable" class="tablesorter" style="width:728px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <tr>
        <td>Euro</td>
        <td align="center">EUR</td>
        <td align="center">€</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td align="center">110.9416</td>
        <td align="center">111.2754</td>
        <td align="center">111.6092</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Australian dollar</td>
        <td align="center">AUD</td>
        <td align="center">$</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td align="center">84.9671</td>
        <td align="center">85.2228</td>
        <td align="center">85.4785</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Canadian dollar</td>
        <td align="center">CAD</td>
        <td align="center">$</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td align="center">81.6167</td>
        <td align="center">81.8623</td>
        <td align="center">82.1079</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this code:

```
tableData = htmlText.find("table", attrs={"class":"tablesorter"})
rows = tableData.findAll('tr')
```

I get all table rows and table cells in one list. So far I have managed to extract one by one currency name, but I really need a list of currency names, like this

```
currencies = ['Euro','Australian dollar','Canadian dollar']
```

What would be the way to achieve this? Later on, I would also need to extract data from the last TD element of each TR element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [70]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [71]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [72]: [tr.find('td').text for tr in soup.findAll('tr')]
Out[72]: [u'Euro', u'Australian dollar', u'Canadian dollar']
```

for the last items:

```
In [73]: [tr.findAll('td')[-1].text for tr in soup.findAll('tr')]
Out[73]: [u'111.6092', u'85.4785', u'82.1079']
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can, and will mark it as "answer". Thank you.